# Prevent "play dist" from zipping up distribution?

Tags: playframework-2.0, sbt

I am using the `dist` command in Play to distribute an application. I would like to access the start script without unzipping the distribution.

Is there a way to prevent the command from zipping up the distribution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run `play stage`.

In **2.2**, this is identical to `play dist` except it doesn't zip. In **2.1** and earlier, it generates a slightly different script and directory layout.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no such possibility before Play 2.2, all you can do is creating a shell script, or i.e. ant task which will dist and then unzip it. If somebody would ask - I don't like this as well ;)